# Customize tooltip in a Chartist timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, chartist.js

I have a timeline using [chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html) and I am using the  [chartist tooltip plugin](https://github.com/Globegitter/chartist-plugin-tooltip)

By default, when you hover over a point the tooltip shows both the x and y values.

How can I customize the tooltip text so that I only show the y value?

**[Chartist tooltip plugin](https://github.com/Globegitter/chartist-plugin-tooltip)**

```
var defaultOptions = {
  currency: undefined, //accepts '£', '$', '€', etc.
  // e.g. 4000 => €4,000
  tooltipFnc: undefined, //accepts function
  // build custom tooltip
  transformTooltipTextFnc: undefined, // accepts function
  // transform tooltip text
  class: undefined, // accecpts 'class1', 'class1 class2', etc.
  // adds class(es) to tooltip wrapper
  anchorToPoint: false, //accepts true or false
  // tooltips do not follow mouse movement -- they are anchored to the point / bar.
  appendToBody: false //accepts true or false
  // appends tooltips to body instead of chart container
};
```

From the plugin documentation it looks like ***transformTooltipTextFnc*** is what I want but I'm not sure how to use it to only display the 'y' value.

**Code**

```
var data = {
  series: [
    {
      name: 'series-1',
      meta: 'series-1',
      data: [
        {x: new Date(143134652600), y: 53},
        {x: new Date(143234652600), y: 40},
        {x: new Date(143340052600), y: 45},        
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'series-2',
      meta: 'series-2',
      data: [
        {x: new Date(143134652600), y: 53},
        {x: new Date(143234652600), y: 35},
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var options = {
  fullwidth: true,
  height: 300,
  axisX: {
      type: Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
      divisor: 6,
      labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
         return moment(value).format('MMM D');
     }
  },
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
  ]
};

new Chartist.Line('#chart1', data, options);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `transformTooltipTextFnc` function receives a single string parameter that contains the X value and Y value separated by a comma. You can use the string split method to return an `Array` with the X value at index 0 and the Y value at index 1.

So, where you have `Chartist.plugins.tooltip()` in your plugins array, replace with:

```
Chartist.plugins.tooltip({
  transformTooltipTextFnc: function(tooltip) {
    var xy = tooltip.split(",");
    return xy[1];
  }
})
```

This is also an opportunity to perform other manipulations. For example, if you wanted to use the Unicode minus sign instead of the default hyphen-minus:

```
var xy = tooltip.split(",");
return xy[1].replace("-", "\u2212");
```

If you wanted to add some units to the numbers, for example, if the numbers were temperatures in degrees Celsius:

```
var xy = tooltip.split(",");
return xy[1] + "\u00B0C";
```